# Error handling with ServiceStack's IStreamWriter & IHasOptions

Tags: servicestack

With an implementation of IStreamWriter and IHasOptions that returns an image/jpeg result, if an error occurs in WriteTo, the global error handler in AppHost is not called, and the image/jpeg header stays, which results in a HTML error (generated by ServiceStack) with an image/jpeg HTTP Header.

Here's an example of how to reproduce this:

```cs
public class SampleStreamWriter : IStreamWriter, IHasOptions
{
    void WriteTo(Stream responseStream)
    {
        // This would actually be a delegate
        throw new ApplicationException("...");
    }

    public IDictionary<string, string> Options
    {
        get
        {
            return new Dictionary<string, string>
                {
                    {HttpHeaders.ContentType, "image/jpeg"}
                };
        }
    }
}
```

Since Options is called before WriteTo, it is not possible to try/catch inside WriteTo and change the Content-Type to e.g. "application/json", and manually override the error response.

How can this be implemented, so that the HTTP Response has the error's Content-Type value, and as a bonus, that the AppHost's ServiceExceptionHandler gets called for logging?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [CompressedFileResult](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.Common/Web/CompressedFileResult.cs) class might be a good example to look at as it inherits IStreamWriter and IHasOptions. There are a few other classes used in testing that inherit from IStreamWriter as well ([StreamWriterResult](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.Endpoints.Tests/ServiceClientsBuiltInResponseTests.cs#L91), [ImageResult](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/tests/ServiceStack.WebHost.IntegrationTests/Services/HelloImage.cs#L59)). Not sure those are as useful.

It seems like the simple answer is to do everything (Validation, get Image, build `byte[]`, etc) before the 'WriteTo' method is called. If your `Try/Catch` is within your Service you can push the exception up and use the Exception handling already provided. Obviously, this doesn't help when `WriteTo` throws an exception but at this point in the [Pipeline](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Architecture-overview#implementation) it seems like you've passed the point of Response manipulation.

Comment: This makes sense; this means there is a tradeoff to make between streaming directly into the response or better error handling. I will then fallback to returning a MemoryStream and writing the Response ContentType directly in the service. Thanks for your help!